# Problem with textwrap module: How to format a text file in paragraphs

Tags: python

I want to read in a text file with python and the textwrap module. The text file is not structured and I want to structure it to a width of 70 tokens and 5 lines per paragraph each

I tried to do it with the textwrap module but it alway throws error messages likethis one: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'expandtabs'

first try:

```
with open("python.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    paragraphs = f.read().split("\n\n")


    textwrap.wrap (paragraphs, width=70)


    print (paragraphs)
```

second try:

```
with open("python.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    paragraphs = f.read().split("\n\n")


    #textwrap.wrap (paragraphs, width=70)
    #print(*textwrap.fill (paragraphs, width=70))
    width = 70
class TextWrapper(width):
    pass

    paragraphs = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=70) 
    paragraphs, (len(paragraphs) + lines - 1) / lines# can be used to have an evenly number of lines

    print (paragraphs)
```

The output should look like a text with each line having the width of 70
and each paragraph having 5 lines

Answer (score 1):

You should pass in the text as text, not as a list:

```
with open("python.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    formatted = textwrap.wrap(f.read(), width=70)
```

Comment: Ah ok thank you. And how can I do it to have paragraphs of 5 lines?

Comment: @besch150: that depends on how you defined "lines" and what your original text looks like.